# How to un-quarantine a neo4j instance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am on Neo4j 5.3 and recently I was working on some `LOAD CSV` commands that panicked the instance. As a result, I have the following error:

```
Database "neo4j" is unavailable, its status is "quarantined".
```

I changed the heap size in the `neo4j.conf` file and restarted the db:

```
server.memory.heap.initial_size=4096m
server.memory.heap.max_size=4096m
```

But still see the same error. Is there a command to start a quarantined instance (after bumping up the heap space)?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved: CALL [dbms.quarantineDatabase](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/manage-databases/errors/#quarantine)("neo4j", false)

Comment: I upvoted your answer, and you now have enough reputation points to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20a%20question,on%20a%20Stack%20Exchange%20site.).